# Loaded an object into a listbox with 2 variables, listbox show only the name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listbox

I have a Class where there a 2  variables `int ID` and `string name`. I made a list of several objects and loaded them onto a listbox. The listbox only show the name. Is there a way to retrieve the ID from the listbox?

```
    class Show
{
    private int _Id;
    private string _Naam;
    private string _Genre;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Naam;
    }
}
```

from a database i make a list of objects.

```
 private void bttn_zoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       foreach (object a in List<show> List) 
          {
             listbox1.Items.Add(a);
          }
    }
```

I hope this is enough

Comment: Over load the object's `ToString` method.

Comment: WinForms, WebForms, WPF, something else?...

Comment: @Johnny so like `listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString(Name, ID);`?

Comment: @Idle_Mind I'm new on this, so  I don't know what you mean :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, here is a super simple example of overriding ToString() to control how the class is displayed in the ListBox, and also how to cast the selected item in the ListBox back to your class type so you can extract values from it.  There are other ways to accomplish this task, but you should understand a bare bones example like this first:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomeClassName sc1 = new SomeClassName();
        sc1.ID = 411;
        sc1.Name = "Information";
        listBox1.Items.Add(sc1);

        SomeClassName sc2 = new SomeClassName();
        sc2.ID = 911;
        sc2.Name = "Emergency";
        listBox1.Items.Add(sc2);
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            SomeClassName sc = (SomeClassName)listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
            label1.Text = "ID: " + sc.ID.ToString();
            label2.Text = "Name: " + sc.Name;
        }
    }

}

public class SomeClassName
{

    public int ID;
    public string Name;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ID.ToString() + ": " + Name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting some of your code would be nice. Have you tried `listBox.items[index].ID`?

Here I'm assuming that *index* is whatever index you're currently searching for.

You can also try `listBox.SelectedItem[index].ID` if you're doing something like an event.

Comment: This won't work without **casting** the "thing" at `listBox.Items[index]` to the correct type...